# How to terminate Java app when dialog box is closed?

Tags: java

I want to terminate execution when user closed the below dialog box

```
String firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first Number");
```

Comment: `firstNumber` will be null...

Comment: Use System.exit() on the close event of dialog box ;)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no close event for a **JOptionPane**.

Luckily **JOptionPane**.*showInputDialog*("message") returns **null** if the user pressed either of the close buttons like so:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String firstNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the first Number");

        if (firstNumber == null)
        {
            System.out.println("X or Close was pressed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("OK was pressed.");
        }
    }
}
```